# Is Passing a Parameter to a method the same as creating an object?

Tags: java

I am learning Servlets and JSP. I am wondering about the "doGet" and other methods that may be overidden. The "doGet" takes 2 params - HTTPServletRequest request, and HTTPServletResponse response. This is my question: The request and response objects are used within the method body but I do not see any object creation e.g. request = new HTTPServletRequest. Are these objects created elsewhere e.g. in the superclass? This is just a Java question really as I often wonder about this with Applets also, i.e. the Graphics g object is passed to the "paint" method but I don't see it's creation anywhere?

GF

Comment: Removed servlet-related tags, since this is a much more basic question than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the two examples you gave, servlets and applets, the code is running inside of a container. Tomcat is the container for servlets and that means that the container provides certain functionality. In this case the container will create the request and response objects and pass it to your servlet for you.

If you write a plain Java program that runs by itself, then you are responsible for creating all objects.

Comment: Yes, that explains it alright. Funny though, most Java books do not actually explain this at all. Surely somebody else has wondered about this in the past. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Grungefreak I think the explanations are there in the books but it may not be stated exactly the way you need it to be. That is the great thing about stackoverflow...you can ask a very specific question and get things stated the way you need it to understand.

Comment: Yes I totally agree. This short thread has cleared up a lot of confusion for me. I am presuming the term "call site" is the section of code that calls (method caller) the actual method concerned?

Comment: Most introductory Java books don't (and shouldn't) use servlets or applets to introduce the basics of the Java language.  I'm sure these issues are described in JEE tutorials and textbooks, but if you don't grasp the Java basics, the points being made in the higher level JEE texts will slip past you.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in any programming language, when a method is called with instances of an object (or any parameter for that matter), yes, those objects are created *somewhere*.

For the most part, you don't have to worry about the *where*, just that *they are* when dealing with them inside of your functions.

Getting back to your question though, while there might be certain situations that an object was created through non-traditional means (depending on the technology stack), you can be assured that more often than not, if you have a reference to an object passed to you in a method you wrote, then it was created using traditonal means somewhere in the call stack (or another, if you have multiple threads).

In the case of Java, this would mean that someone called `new ...` at some point, and made it available to the call site of your method in order to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, I accept that I may be digging pretty deep here but I am trying to get a real indepth view of what's going on. In the case of the "paint()" method in applets, a Graphics object is passed in. When the applet runs inside a browser, does the Java plugin somehow create the graphics object as I cannot see where else it is created?

GF

Comment: @GrungeFreak: Yes, that's exactly what it does.  The JVM will interact with whatever platform it is on to create the Graphics object, and then when appropriate, call your paint method, passing the instance in.

Answer (score 1):

It's created by the web server (tomcat, for example), and it calling your servlet with this parameters

Answer (score 0):

The objects are created at the call-site. I.e. whoever calls the method is responsible for creating the objects that he/she passed to the method as parameters (unless he passes already existing objects, of course, but those have previously been created somewhere as well).

Comment: As a general statement this is not true. The object creation can occur in a number of different places. It doesn't *have* to be at the call-site. It's just that the call site has to have access to the created object it wants to pass as a parameter.

Comment: @casperOne: That's why I wrote "unless he passes already existing objects".

Answer (score 0):

all methods in servlets are invoked by servlet container such as tomcat